# Xamarin VSTS HockeyApp Parse Error

Tags: xamarin, azure-devops, hockeyapp, visual-studio-app-center

I get a parse error on my phone when I downloaded my Xamarin application from the HockeyApp. The HockeyApp receives the build from my VSTS build/release and Visual Studio App center. But, when I debug my app from Visual Studio on the same phone, my app works without any problem. So, I think the parse error is caused by VSTS or by Visual Studio App Center. Can anyone help me? Thanks, Marcel

This question was marked as duplicate. I think it isn't. There are no forum items handled the particular case using Xamarin, VSTS, HockeyApp, and App center and my problem.

Comment: is your device listed in the provisioning profile that the app was built with?

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you for your response. I don't know what you mean with the provisioning profile. I Google'd for a while for this term. The only hits I can find is about IOS???? Can you explain what you mean with provisioning profile?

Comment: Is it an Android app?  Nothing in your question or tags says that.

Comment: Yes, it is an Android app.

Comment: After some research I solved the problem. My Android application wasn't signed in the VSTS build definition. After I changed this step so that my app was really signed, I runs on my device without any problem. The reason why the app was running OK when I debugged it in Visual Studio, was the fact that Visual Studio signs the app before deploying to my phone.